# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition: Error „lc.exe exited with code -1“

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to use an old VS project with an external assembly.

I read that lc.exe is for licensing of external assemblies and most likely the license is no longer valid. I tried to install a trial of the external assembly, but the problem is still the same.

This error is quite common:
[How to fix build error in Visual Studio: '"LC.exe" exited with code -1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284/how-to-fix-the-following-build-error-in-visual-studio-2005-lc-exe-exited-wit)
and many other google results tell to delete the licenses.licx file which will be regenerated during the next build – it is not regenerated during build in my project.

Is there any more detailed report of LC.exe then "error code -1"?

I have no idea how to handle this error.

**EDIT:**

The more detailed error is:

> "licenses.licx(1): error LC0003: Unable to resolve type '', ''

where '', '' are the names of the components which I installed as a trial.

Comment: Figure out the command being sent to LC (turn up your build verbosity) and run that from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for this idea - but where do I turn up the build verbosity?

Comment: Check the Build tab under the properties for your project.  Otherwise, there is a command line switch you can pass in ... I'd guess /verbose, that you can add to the command line params you can add on that page.  I don't know offhand, but a little search engine fu will do you good.  If you get more info and are still stuck, add your findings to an [edit].

Comment: Browsing the configuration explorer I do not see any command line settings. Maybe taht is a limitation of the community edition?!
I can choose release or debug, both only for "any CPU".

Comment: Eh, muh guess was wrong.  But remember!  Use your search engines. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The solution I found is to throw the old 'licenses.licx' file out. I do this by manually deleting the file in the "Properties" folder of my project and removing the line referencing it in the *.csproj-file.

[Look at this blog-post here](https://michlg.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/lc-exe-exited-with-code-1/).