# How to Configure Visual Studio to use NETFX 4.7 Tools when NETFX 4.6.1 Tools are also installed

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Merge during WebApp publishing from Visual Studio 2017 15.2 is still using asp_net.merge.exe in version 4.6.1 (as per publishing output log), not corresponding to .Net Framework version 4.7 installed. Framework 4.7 version is set as a target framework for the project.

Both merge tools are installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\aspnet_merge.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\aspnet_merge.exe
```

How to configure Visual Studio to start using 4.7 version of aspnet_merge.exe?

Comment: aspnet_merge.exe hasn't been updated for long time. There is no difference between these two version. The latest version of aspnet_merge.exe was released through nuget package. Here is the link - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Merge/5.0.0-beta2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error, Im using Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.5), and need compile for .net 4.7.2; after many testing, this works for my:

1. Install the [latest Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
2. Install the [.net 4.7.2 Developer Pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)
3. Configure the installer of Visual Studio to target the .net 4.7.2 SDK
4. Specify the path to the SDK editing directly in the [projectname].csproj file, add:

`<TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>`

Answer (score -1):

May you can't to do it, the CLR is one per dist, see about:[Forum Asp.NET](http://%20https://forums.asp.net/t/2129775.aspx?project%20net%20framework%20version%20and%20compile%20publish)

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. Please do not post link only answers. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). And your link is broken, so it does not provide answer at all.