# error MSB6006: "lc.exe" exited with code -1

Tags: visual-studio, build, compiler-errors, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I can't build my application anymore,
every time I try to compile the following error arises.

> error MSB6006: "lc.exe" exited with code -1

I've never changed anything within the `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` file (or any other file which is related to MSBuild).

---

*Full path to the file:*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
```

*Rows where the error seems to be/arise:*

```
<LC
    Sources="@(_LicxFile)"
    LicenseTarget="$(TargetFileName)"
    OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
    OutputLicense="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).licenses"
    ReferencedAssemblies="@(ReferencePathWithRefAssemblies);@(ReferenceDependencyPaths)"
    NoLogo="$(NoLogo)"
    ToolPath="$(LCToolPath)"
    SdkToolsPath="$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)"
    EnvironmentVariables="$(LCEnvironment)"
    MSBuildArchitecture="$(LCMSBuildArchitecture)"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"
    >
```

---

The main problem here is that I can compile every other application, but not my most important one which is written in C# WPF with the .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Does anyone have a clue why I might can't compile the solution?

Comment: Hi, as I know, `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` is a msbuild system file and when it turns out errors, it means that your project has something wrong. Did your project has any errors or underlines? If you have any nuget packages with warnings, you could reinstall them. Besdes, you could set Build log to Detailed to see the specific warning. In addition, please share `xxxx.csproj` file with us to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error MSB6006: “lc.exe” exited with code -1

**This error** means that your project has something wrong rather than `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` file

**In fact, to see the specific error**, you should set your Build Output log to **Diagnostic/Detailed** by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Diagnostic/Detailed`. Then when you build again, you can see the detailed info about it.

And you can try to follow these syggestions:

1. Please check whether you have any warnings on your nuget packages. If so, please reinstall them or just use `update-Package -reinstall` under **Package Manage Console**.
2. If you have any **post(pre)-build event**(Right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`Build Event`), please check whether the command has some errors.
3. If you have licenses.licx files, you should exclude them from your project.
4. you can try to create a new WPF project and then add the same as the previous project to test if it is the issue of your project.
5. [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in case there are something with your VS Environment or update your VS to the latest version.

**In addition**, if possible, please share the `xxxxx.csproj` file of your WPF project with us to troubleshoot your issue quickly. Also, there is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284/how-to-fix-build-error-in-visual-studio-lc-exe-exited-with-code-1) about this error.

Comment: Your tip with the detailed output is gold! I was able to fix the issue by manuelly recreating the `licenses.licx` files with no content.

Comment: I had to clear all the lines from licenses.licx after upgrading from VS 2017 to VS 2019 to avoid error MSB6006: “lc.exe” exited with code -1. But I am not sure why and why the components don't need the licences keys anymore.